# ck editor reactive form angular 6 not working

Tags: angular

ck editor in angular 6 reactive form is not working. Getting an error with

> No value accessor for form control with name: 'description'

I have imported ck editor in my app.module.ts and in current page. But still I am getting the same error. Given below is my cms-add html page :

```
  <form [formGroup]="addCMSForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <div class="box-body">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group padding">
                  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <ckeditor formControlName="description" #description skin="moono-lisa" language="en" [fullPage]="false"></ckeditor>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>

              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group padding">
                  <button [disabled]="addCMSForm.invalid" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                  <a [routerLink]="['/cms-list']" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Back</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
```

I have created the typescript page And this is my cms-add.ts page.Can you please resolve my issue .ck editor in reactive form .

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule, ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";
import { CKEditorModule } from 'ngx-ckeditor';

@Component({
  selector: 'cms-add',
  templateUrl: './cms-add.component.html'

})
export class CMSAddComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  title = 'Add CMS';
  addCMSForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.addCMSForm = this.formBuilder.group({               
      description: ['']   
    });
  }
```

It's showing error as No value accessor for form control with name: 
'description'

> ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name:
>   'description'
>           at _throwError (vendor.js:53593)
>           at setUpControl (vendor.js:53503)
>           at FormGroupDirective.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroupDirective.addControl
>   (vendor.js:56315)
>           at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName._setUpControl
>   (vendor.js:56820)
>           at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName.ngOnChanges
>   (vendor.js:56770)

can you please help to solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

I saw you import `CKEditorModule` in your component.

In `ngx-ckeditor` document: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-ckeditor, You should import `CKEditorModule` module in your module then use it in your component.

I hope this could help you.